# Getting very low accuracy while fine tuning Inception v3 pre trained model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am using Inception v3 model for identification of disease present in a Chest XRay image. For training I am using NIH Chest XRay Dataset. I have 14 different classes of diseases present in the dataset and also I have reduced the original image resolution to reduce the dataset size on disk. As I don't have a GPU I am using Google Colab to train my model and I am taking only 300 images per classs for all minority classes and 400 images for 'No Finding' class (Majority class). Please point out the bugs in my code if any and please suggest me some other approaches so that I can achieve better accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

np.random.seed(42)


rn.seed(12345)


session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

from keras import backend as K


tf.set_random_seed(1234)

sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)


from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Reshape, Lambda
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# import os.path

'''F1 score calculation class'''

# import numpy as np
# from keras.callbacks import Callback
# from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score

# class Metrics(Callback):
#   def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
#     self.val_f1s = []
#     self.val_recalls = []
#     self.val_precisions = []

#   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
#     val_predict = (np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.model.validation_data[0]))).round()
#     val_targ = self.model.validation_data[1]
#     _val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ, val_predict)
#     _val_recall = recall_score(val_targ, val_predict)
#     _val_precision = precision_score(val_targ, val_predict)
#     self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
#     self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
#     self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
#     print(" — val_f1: %f — val_precision: %f — val_recall %f" % (_val_f1, _val_precision, _val_recall))
#     return

# metrics = Metrics()

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# dimensions of our images.
#Inception input size
img_width, img_height = 299, 299

top_layers_checkpoint_path = 'cp.top.best.hdf5'
fine_tuned_checkpoint_path = 'cp.fine_tuned.best.hdf5'
new_extended_inception_weights = 'final_weights.hdf5'

train_data_dir = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Sample-300-XRay-Dataset/train'
validation_data_dir = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Sample-300-XRay-Dataset/test'

nb_train_samples = 3528
nb_validation_samples = 896

top_epochs = 50
fit_epochs = 50

batch_size = 24

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
#x =Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
#x= Dropout(0.3)(x)
# and a logistic layer -- we have 15 classes
predictions = Dense(15, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

if os.path.exists(top_layers_checkpoint_path):
    model.load_weights(top_layers_checkpoint_path)
    print ("Checkpoint '" + top_layers_checkpoint_path + "' loaded.")

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non-trainable)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# prepare data augmentation configuration
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


#Save the model after every epoch.
mc_top = ModelCheckpoint(top_layers_checkpoint_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)

#Save the TensorBoard logs.
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
#model.fit_generator(...)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=top_epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=[mc_top, tb])

# at this point, the top layers are well trained and we can start fine-tuning
# convolutional layers from inception V3. We will freeze the bottom N layers
# and train the remaining top layers.

# let's visualize layer names and layer indices to see how many layers
# we should freeze:
# for i, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers):
#    print(i, layer.name)


#Save the model after every epoch.
mc_fit = ModelCheckpoint(fine_tuned_checkpoint_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)


if os.path.exists(fine_tuned_checkpoint_path):
    model.load_weights(fine_tuned_checkpoint_path)
    print ("Checkpoint '" + fine_tuned_checkpoint_path + "' loaded.")

# we chose to train the top 2 inception blocks, i.e. we will freeze
# the first 172 layers and unfreeze the rest:
for layer in model.layers[:172]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[172:]:
   layer.trainable = True

# we need to recompile the model for these modifications to take effect
# we use SGD with a low learning rate
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# we train our model again (this time fine-tuning the top 2 inception blocks
# alongside the top Dense layers
#model.fit_generator(...)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=fit_epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=[mc_fit, tb])

model.save_weights(new_extended_inception_weights)
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477777/2099607) might be relevant.

Comment: The person in above post is getting high validation accuracy but very low training accuracy. But I am getting lower training as well as validation accuracy. Is there any problem in my dataset or my approach??

Comment: Well, after a quick check of your code I could not see any apparent problems in it. So I thought maybe you have the same (and not exactly the same) issue as in the link I provided. Did you try the solution there?

Comment: I tried the solution in the link above. But it didn't improved accuracy of my model.