# Constant Validation Accuracy with a high loss in machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to do create an image classification model using Inception V3 with 2 classes. I have 1428 images which are balanced about 70/30. When I run my model I get a pretty high loss of as well as a constant validation accuracy. What might be causing this constant value?

```
data = np.array(data, dtype="float")/255.0
labels = np.array(labels,dtype ="uint8")

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(
                            data,labels, 
                            test_size=0.2, 
                            random_state=42) 

img_width, img_height = 320, 320 #InceptionV3 size

train_samples =  1145 
validation_samples = 287
epochs = 20

batch_size = 32

base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights ='imagenet',
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3))

model_top = keras.models.Sequential()
model_top.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None)),
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(350,activation='relu'))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model_top(base_model.output))


for layer in model.layers[:30]:
  layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(
                    lr=0.00001,
                    beta_1=0.9,
                    beta_2=0.999,
                    epsilon=1e-08),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

#Image Processing and Augmentation 
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
          zoom_range = 0.05,
          #width_shift_range = 0.05, 
          height_shift_range = 0.05,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          vertical_flip = True,
          fill_mode ='nearest') 

val_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()


train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        trainX, 
        trainY,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow(
                testX,
                testY,
                batch_size=batch_size)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs = epochs, 
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_samples//batch_size,
    callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint])
```

This is my log when I run my model:

```
Epoch 1/20
35/35 [==============================]35/35[==============================] - 52s 1s/step - loss: 0.6347 - acc: 0.6830 - val_loss: 0.6237 - val_acc: 0.6875

Epoch 2/20
35/35 [==============================]35/35 [==============================] - 14s 411ms/step - loss: 0.6364 - acc: 0.6756 - val_loss: 0.6265 - val_acc: 0.6875

Epoch 3/20
35/35 [==============================]35/35 [==============================] - 14s 411ms/step - loss: 0.6420 - acc: 0.6743 - val_loss: 0.6254 - val_acc: 0.6875

Epoch 4/20
35/35 [==============================]35/35 [==============================] - 14s 414ms/step - loss: 0.6365 - acc: 0.6851 - val_loss: 0.6289 - val_acc: 0.6875

Epoch 5/20
35/35 [==============================]35/35 [==============================] - 14s 411ms/step - loss: 0.6359 - acc: 0.6727 - val_loss: 0.6244 - val_acc: 0.6875

Epoch 6/20
35/35 [==============================]35/35 [==============================] - 15s 415ms/step - loss: 0.6342 - acc: 0.6862 - val_loss: 0.6243 - val_acc: 0.6875
```

Comment: If you have not normalized the images, then pass `rescale=1/255.` to `ImageDataGenerator` instances and see if it helps.

Comment: Try to add ReduceLearningRate callback from Keras

Comment: I've normalized my data the following way, is this correct?   data = np.array(data, dtype="float")/255.0

Comment: I am not sure but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477777/2099607) helps you. Further, when you are replying back to a specific user in the comments section, please use @their_username at the beginning of your comment to notify them. I was not notified of your response. Yes, the normalization you have done is correct.

Comment: The key thing to notice is that your val_loss **is** decreasing. So your network is slowly learning, but not enough to adjust any of its prediction yet which is why the accuracy is not changing.

Try making your learning rate larger, maybe `l=0.001` as others have suggested.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have too low learning rate and too few epochs. try with `lr = 0.001` and `epochs = 100`.

Comment: This also seems like the best first approach to me. Try with different learning rates first. A learning rate of lr=0.00001 can be too small and make the loss drop very slowly (what you refer as 'constant').

Answer (score 4):

Your accuracy is 68.25%. Given that your classes are split roughly 70/30 it is likely that your model is just predicting the same thing every time, ignoring the input. That would give the accuracy you are seeing. Your model has not yet learned from your data.

As Novak said, your learning rate seems very low, so maybe try increasing that first to see if that helps.